# ExpressJS - Swagger - Swagger not working when I Added Bearer Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I've defined the security definitions.

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "Bearer": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "in": "header",
      "name": "Authorization"
    }
  },
```

And this is my path :

```
"/post/user": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Authenticated User"
        ],
        "summary": "All User's Posts",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "user-posts",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "All user's posts.",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Post"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": {
          "Bearer": []
        }   
      }
    },
```

This is how I initialize my swagger-ui-express :

```js
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

When I tried to login and add the token to the Authorize option in the top right and executed the protected path, Swagger will be loading forever. Even Swagger is not hitting the endpoint because there is no log printed in the server console.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console on the Swagger UI page?

Comment: There is no error. that's one of the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution ?